# Drop down values: Percent complete. Not sure which format is best

Tags: drop-down-list

I have a filter page that allows users to filter checklist items, based on their percentage of completion (0-100%).

Initially was thinking of using these values as a range;
Less Than 25%
Less Than 50%
Less Than 75%
Greater Than 75%

But I am having second thoughts. Wondering if anyone has an alternative idea. I also thought of have values in sets of 10 percents - 10%, 20%, 30%, etc.

Comment: Is the user able to enter any arbitrary value for a percentage of completion on a checklist item? Or is it a set of values as well?

Comment: How many items? Are they downloads or user controlled steps? How quickly do the items become complete?

Comment: They cannot enter any value for a percent complete. They must be a set of values. The checklist percentage is calculated by how much of the checklist a user has completed. Then an admin user can filter on a checklists by those percent values.

Comment: @user15921 So the items themselves cannot have any value like 1.25% complete, correct? But the overall completion of a checklist is a calculated value so it could end up being something like 35.6%, correct?

Comment: Technically, yes, but we would never display a percent to the end user as a decimal. Just round it up or down.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to make a trade-off and weigh up what is more important;

a) having accurate values.

b) having the users working on the actual tasks they're completing.

The fewer the number of values to select the lower the accuracy of the value it's reflecting, but the more values there are for selection the more often the user will have to edit it.

Do you want the users spending all their time editing the 'Percentage Complete' field? Yes, it's useful for reporting but it's going to take them away from performing the actual task.

As for how to do it; instead of a dropdown why not use the same approach that Excel uses? Select the 'Percentage' size (in Excel's case this is used for Zooming) and give them a bunch of radio buttons for quick entry, and a custom value box if they want to be accurate.

[image: percentage]

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming that the user is capable of filtering based on a number of criteria; therefore adding to many ‘checkbox’ type filters might clutter the interface slightly.

It could be worth trying something a bit more visual, like a slider. You’ve said that the user can’t filter by any amount of %, so the slider could more in increments of 10%, 25% or whatever.

[image]

If it’s important that the user is capable of filtering by both ‘greater than’ and ‘less than’ a certain percent, we could add a dropdown element.

[image]

Just an idea, would probably want some refining but it's one potential solution :-) Good Luck!!

Comment: Yep, thought of the sliders too, but have concerns over accessibility. Thanks for the answer though.